# installing R 4.0.2 in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, r-4.0.0

I am trying to install R version 4.0.2 on ubuntu 18.04 but it shows this message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 4.0.3-1.2004.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: r-recommended (= 4.0.3-1.2004.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Receiving "Unmet dependency" while installing r-base on Ubuntu 14.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28273441/receiving-unmet-dependency-while-installing-r-base-on-ubuntu-14-10). Or maybe [Having difficulty with re-installing R in Ubuntu 18.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62166039/having-difficulty-with-re-installing-r-in-ubuntu-18-04)

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove problematic PPA (it does no publish packages for 18.04 LTS - bionic) first with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:grass/grass-stable
```

and then update your package lists

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and install new updates with their dependencies by

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

You have added R 3.5 repository (see bionic-cran35 in its URL), instead of needed R 4.0 (bionic-cran40). You have to remove wrong repository with

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/'
```

and then add correct one:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/'
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-core r-recommended
```

Comment: Maybe his could help you then. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61586021/is-it-impossible-to-install-r-4-0-on-ubuntu-18-04-4-lts-because-r-base-core-requ

Answer (score 0):

In order to install the last R version in Ubuntu LTS >= 16.04. (amongst other 18.04) follow the [instructions at CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/). If you have already installed the distro version of R remove it with the package manager.

Here, I made a summarized version of the instructions.
Note that this instructions are valid **for any LTS**. I tried them with 18.04. and worked smoothly.

1. update indices

`sudo apt update -qq`

2. install two helper packages we need

`sudo apt install --no-install-recommends software-properties-common dirmngr`

3. Add the signing key (by Michael Rutter) for these repos

`wget -qO- https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/marutter_pubkey.asc | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/cran_ubuntu_key.asc`

4. Add the R 4.0 repo from CRAN

`sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs)-cran40/"`

5. Install R and its dependences

`sudo apt install --no-install-recommends r-base`

6. Ready, you can execute R by just entering `R` on your terminal.